# (Why) is there no complexity class for linear space (O(n))?

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, time-complexity, space-complexity

tldr: I'm looking for any general information about the linear space complexity class. e.g. is there a complete problem for it?

the Quantified Boolean Formula (QBF) problem is a P-space complete problem. I use the definition for QBF from [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397506005585), which got its definition from [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/meyer/meyer-stockmeyer-word-probs.pdf). It seems trivial to me that there's an exponential solution that uses linear space by using depth-first search. So this P-space complete problem uses linear space, but this does not mean that P-space=linear space. We have:

Linear space $\subseteq$ P-space $\subseteq$ Exp-time

In the (though unlikely) case that P=P-space, I was thinking about the contradiction/paradox situation that:

- Linear space takes *exponential time*
- P-space takes *polynomial time*
- Exp-time takes *exponential time*

which, because of the likely contradiction, makes me want to conclude that

P = P-space $\implies$ P = P-space = Linear space

I wanted to think about the contradiction/paradox further and I wanted to lookup information about the linear space complexity class. None seems to be available. What am I overlooking. Is this complexity class not interesting? It is not even mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_complexity_classes).

Comment: side-note: because of writing it down it seems a paradox *and* the implication seems correct: Maybe P=P-space=Linear space, while it takes exponential time when given only O(n) space.

Comment: The space hierarchy theorem separates linear space from polynomial space.

Comment: Also, non-deterministic linear space is a well-known complexity class, CSL (context-sensitive languages).

Comment: The "duplicate" question gives a language which is complete for DSPACE(n). If you have any further questions on this class, please ask a new question.